# Are all edits in Photos permanently reversible?

Tags: photos, video, photos.app, video-editing, undo-redo

When I edit photos and videos in Apple's Photos.app on desktop or iPhone/iPad it appears that the original video is stored forever, so any edits I make can be undone. I can crop, rotate, retouch, apply adjustments, and trim, then later come back and hit the "revert" button to restore them to their original form.

There are some operations (trim) that give me the option to save a new version that can't be reverted.

Other than saving or exporting a new version and deleting the original, is there any operation I can perform (intentionally or not) that makes irreversible changes or causes existing changes to become irreversible?

I'm interested in answers for both desktop MacOS and iOS (if different).